# Autoscaling in dynamodb though cloud formation doesn't fallback after manual intervention

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I have autoscaling configured in one of my dynamoDB table which is deployed through cloudformation. Once i have disabled the autoscaling though the console. Now when i deploy the autoscaling through cloudformation again, its disabled though it should be enabled. I have already tried update policy but doesn't seems to help.

```
UpdatePolicy:
  AutoScalingReplacingUpdate:
    WillReplace: Boolean
```

Is the cloudformation not smart enough to override the manual changes? And is there any specific way to handle this.

I noticed that the drift status does not capture the manual changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [UpdatePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) attribute doesn't support the [`AWS::DynamoDB::Table`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) resource type.

According to the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html):

> Use the UpdatePolicy attribute to specify how AWS CloudFormation handles updates to the AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup, AWS::Lambda::Alias, or AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup resources.

Note that for drift detection to pick up on changes, you'll need to make sure that all properties in your cloudformation resource are explicitly set (including default values) in order for it to properly detect drift.

See in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-drift.html)

> CloudFormation only determines drift for property values that are explicitly set, either through the stack template or by specifying template parameters. This does not include default values for resource properties. To have CloudFormation track a resource property for purposes of determining drift, explicitly set the property value, even if you are setting it to the default value.

Hope this helps!